# Как применить значения цикла к остальным переменным?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Не могу понять как применить изменившиеся значения цикла ко всем переменным. Есть ли для этого какой-нибудь оператор? Или я должен что-то править?

```
import math
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt, exp

print("Задача Ламе", '\n')
J = 2  # Номер случая
a_cm = 22
b_cm = 36
sigT = 160 * 1e6
E = 120000 * 1e6
k = 2.28
v = 0.34
b = b_cm * 0.01
a = a_cm * 0.01
print("Исходные данные")
print("    a,мм    b,мм    SigmaT, Мпа    E, Мпа                k          v")
print("   ", a, "  ", b, "  ", sigT, "  ", E, "      ", k, "    ", v, '\n')
# Допустимое давление
sigma = sigT / k
pmax = sigma * (b ** 2 - a ** 2) / (2 * b ** 2)
pa = pmax
pb = 0
# A и B
A = ((pa * a ** 2) - (pb * b ** 2)) / ((b ** 2) - (a ** 2))
B = ((pa - pb) * ((a ** 2) * (b ** 2))) / ((b ** 2) - (a ** 2))
# Вычисления
N = 5
shag = (b - a) / 10
r = a

##################################################################3
for r in (a, b, shag):
    sigma_r = A - B / (r ** 2)
    sigma_fi = A + B / (r ** 2)
    if J == 1:
        sigma_z = 0
    if J == 2:
        sigma_z = (pa * (a ** 2) - pb * (b ** 2)) / ((b ** 2) - (a ** 2))
    if J == 3:
        sigma_z = 2 * v * A

#####################################################################
u = 1 / E * (A * (1 - v) * r + B * (1 + v) / r - v * r * sigma_z)
eps_r = 1 / E * (A * (1 - v) - B * (1 + v) / r / r - v * sigma_z)
eps_r1 = 1 / E * (sigma_r - v * (sigma_r + sigma_z))
eps_fi = 1 / E * (A * (1 - v) + B * (1 + v) / r / r - v * sigma_z)
eps_fi1 = 1 / E * (sigma_fi - v * (sigma_r + sigma_z))
eps_z = 1 / E * (sigma_z - 2 * v * A)
eps_z1 = 1 / E * (sigma_z - v * (sigma_r + sigma_fi))
eps_mis = 1 / sqrt(2) * sqrt((eps_r - eps_fi) ** 2) + ((eps_fi - eps_z) ** 2) + ((eps_z - eps_r) ** 2)
er = (E - (1 - 2 * v)) * (eps_r + eps_fi + eps_z)
sigm = (sigma_r + sigma_fi + sigma_z) / 3
sigm_is = sqrt(1.5) * sqrt((sigma_r - sigm) ** 2) + ((sigma_fi - sigma_z) ** 2) + ((sigma_z - sigm) ** 2)
sigma_is1 = 1 / sqrt(2) * sqrt((sigma_r - sigma_fi) ** 2) + ((sigma_fi - sigma_z) ** 2) + ((sigma_z - sigma_r) ** 2)


for r in np.arange(a, b, shag):
    print(repr("%.4f" %(r*1e2)), "   ", repr("%.4f" %(sigma_r/1e6)), "   ", repr("%.3f" %(sigma_fi/1e6)), "  ", repr("%.2f" %(sigma_z)), "  ", repr("%.2f" %(sigm_is/1e6)), "  ", repr("%.2f" %(u*1e3)),
          "  ", repr("%.2f" %(eps_r*1e3)), "  ", repr("%.2f" %(eps_fi*1e3)), "  ", repr("%.2f" %(eps_z*1e4)), "  ", repr("%.2f" %(eps_mis*1e3)), sep="|")
```

Собственно, выходит очевидный результат, где изменяется только первый столбец (r). Как это исправить? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: numpy предоставляет отличные механизмы как для вычислений, так и для хранения таблиц с данными. Можно посмотреть на pandas. А так - список со значениями.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать глобальную переменную и изменять её. Такой себе способ, но если нет возможности использовать numpy, то лучше сделать так.